# Xamarin debug.keystore on different PCs

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-keystore

I have added a google sing-in api into my xamarin.forms project. (I have done it according to [this](https://causerexception.com/2017/12/03/google-native-login-with-xamarin-forms/) guide). And it works well, but there is another PC with this project, and SHA1 debug key on that PC is different from the key on my PC. So a google sign-in does not work on the second PC. How can I make it works on both PCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way will be to use the same keystore on both machines.
 The guide you shared contains a detailed information on how to generate a keystore. Alternatively you can read this [official guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/signing/keystore-signature/).
Once it is generated you will have to use this keystore to [sign](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/signing/) your apk.

P.S.: If you are completely new to Android I would highly recommend to get familiar with the signing concept and the [official Android guid](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)e is the best place for this.